# Replacing long blank space with perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to replace a line of commented text in a file with nothing, using perl. Like this:

```
## Some text                                                            ##
```

I tried this command:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/## Some text                                                           ##//g' file.php
```

But that didn't work. Is there any way to do it with blank spaces that are that long?

Comment: `s/## Some text\s##/g`

Comment: That's not a valid `s///` because there's no replacement.  Also, `\s` is only a single whitespace character.  You'd have to do `s/## Some text\s*##//g`.

Comment: @AndyLester -- Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the line, but remove the text:

```
$ perl -pi -e 's/## Some text\s+##//'
```

If you want to remove the line completely:

```
$ perl -ni -e 'print unless /## Some text\s+##/'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all lines that are only comments and that comments are created with a leading # character then all you have to do is:

```
perl -i -ne 'print unless (m/^\s*#/);' file_name
```

the m match uses ^ (beginning of line) \s* (zero or more white spaces)

If on the other hand you want to remove that specific line, then use -n instead of -p like this:

```
perl -i -ne 'print unless (m//## Some text                                                           #/);' file_name
```

The reason your code didn't "work" is that the -p option is always going to give you a print.
Type:

```
perldoc perlrequick
```

and

```
perldoc perlretut
```

for more information on reg. expressions. Type:

```
perldoc perlrun
```

for more information on -n and -p options.